# Accessing user's pages on Facebook to read only

Tags: facebook, api, permissions

On Facebook, is there any permission other than manage_pages that allows accessing the user's pages but without the ability to manage or modify them?

All I need is to get a list of the user's pages and their attributes, and if possible I prefer not to ask for more permissions than I really need.

Comment: Nope, what you can do with manage_pages depends on what the user can do on the specific page(s), i.e. which role he has. The whole page management permission system is highly flawed IMHO – for example it should give me as a user the ability to grant permission only for a single page, but it doesn’t …